# JAXB Fixed Attribute not set during marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

JAXB seems not to be able to set a fixed attribute value by default.  Is this expected behavior, or something I'm doing wrong?

I have an xsd like:

```
<element name="AccountCategory" type="tns:Integer"></element>
<xs:complexType name="Integer">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:int">
            <xs:attribute name="e-dtype" fixed="int"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Marshalling a java object created with new produces:

```
<AccountCategory>5</AccountCategory>
```

Java:

```
com.sample.Integer val = new com.sample.Integer();
val.setValue(5);
parentObject.setAccountCategory(val);
```

I am able to manually set the attribute value and it works fine.  Also if I just reset it to its own value it also works.  Seems like the marshaller is not using the get method when generating the XML?

```
val.setEDtype(val.getEDtype());
```

Results in

```
<AccountCategory e-dtype="int">5</AccountCategory>
```

The generated .java below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Integer", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class Integer {

@XmlValue
protected int value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "e-dtype")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
protected String eDtype;

/**
 * Gets the value of the value property.
 * 
 */
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the value property.
 * 
 */
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the eDtype property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getEDtype() {
    if (eDtype == null) {
        return "int";
    } else {
        return eDtype;
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the eDtype property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setEDtype(String value) {
    this.eDtype = value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with jaxb binding fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217013/3517383).

```
<schema targetNamespace="https://stackoverflow.com/example" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        jaxb:version="2.0">
  <annotation>
    <appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" />
    </appinfo>
  </annotation>
  ...
</schema>
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [XML Schema Part 0 - 2.2.1 Occurrence Constraints](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints):

> The `fixed` attribute is used in both attribute and element declarations to ensure that the attributes and elements are set to particular values. For example, `po.xsd` contains a declaration for the `country` attribute, which is declared with a `fixed` value `US`. This declaration means that the appearance of a `country` attribute in an instance document is optional (the default value of `use` is `optional`), although if the attribute does appear, its value must be `US`, and if the attribute does not appear, the schema processor will provide a `country` attribute with the value `US`.

So, as you can see, because your attribute is `optional`, it will not be generated unless you give a value, but that value must be `int` to be schema compliant.

Calling `get` will give you the default/fixed value, *as it should*,
and generation will omit attribute if not set, *as it should*.

And no, the marshaller is not using the `get` method, because `@XmlAccessorType` is `XmlAccessType.FIELD`.

Comment: OK makes sense.  But if I update the xsd to make the attribute required the same behavior persists.  Something else I miss?     <xs:attribute name="e-dtype" use="required" fixed="int"/>

Comment: Yes, you're missing the fact that XML *generation* doesn't enforce the XML schema, so you can generate XML that is not compliant with the schema, including occurrence constraints (`use`, `minOccurs`, `maxOccurs`). See section "Validation and Well-Formedness" in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty xjc binding to resolve the issue.